# EF 6 Fluent Configuration - recursively nested objects with parent - TPH

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, fluent-interface

I have the following entity which has a collection of itself and a parent property which I want to be null if it is the root widget:

```
public class CanvasWidgetQuery
{
    public int CanvasWidgetId { get; set; }

    public int? ParentCanvasWidgetId { get; set; }
    public virtual CanvasWidgetQuery ParentCanvasWidget { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CanvasWidgetQuery> InnerCanvasWidgets { get; set; }

}
```

Because `CanvasWidgetQuery` is actually just a base class (might as well be abstract but I'm not putting abstract until I see it work without it). I wanted to create a generic mapping configuration to map derived types of `CanvasWidgetQuery`:

```
public class CanvasWidgetQueryMap<TCanvasWidgetQuery> : EntityTypeConfiguration<TCanvasWidgetQuery>
    where TCanvasWidgetQuery : CanvasWidgetQuery
{
    public CanvasWidgetQueryMap() 
    {
        this.HasKey(q => q.CanvasWidgetId);

        this.HasMany(w => w.InnerCanvasWidgets)
            .WithOptional(w => w.ParentCanvasWidget)
            .HasForeignKey(w => w.ParentCanvasWidgetId);

    }
}
```

Regardless of the derived type, they all have those properties but unfortunately it complains about the `WithOptional` call (2 errors at once):

```
 Error  1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'CanvasWidgetQuery' to 'TCanvasWidgetQuery'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) 


 Error  2   Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type 'System.Func<CanvasWidgetQuery,TCanvasWidgetQuery>' because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type
```

If I move this up a level to the mapping of the actual derived type:

```
 public class SearchCanvasWidgetQueryMap : CanvasWidgetQueryMap<SearchCanvasWidgetQuery>
{
    public SearchCanvasWidgetQueryMap() 
    {
        this.HasMany(w => w.InnerCanvasWidgets)
            .WithOptional(w => w.ParentCanvasWidget)
            .HasForeignKey(w => w.ParentCanvasWidgetId);
    }
}
```

Now it complains that it cannot implicity convert `CanvasWidgetQuery` into `SearchCanvasWidgetQuery` meanwhile:

```
public class SearchCanvasWidgetQuery : CanvasWidgetQuery
{

}
```

How can I accomplish what I'm after

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried defining the map for the base class which holds the properties which define the hierarchy?

e.g:

```
public class CanvasWidgetQueryMap<CanvasWidgetQuery> : EntityTypeConfiguration<CanvasWidgetQuery>
{
    public CanvasWidgetQueryMap() 
    {
        this.HasKey(q => q.CanvasWidgetId);

        this.HasMany(w => w.InnerCanvasWidgets)
            .WithOptional(w => w.ParentCanvasWidget)
            .HasForeignKey(w => w.ParentCanvasWidgetId);

    }
}
```

There's some good additional information in the answer here: [CTP 4 doesn't consider base class properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362641/ctp-4-doesnt-consider-base-class-properties) which might be helpful if the above doesn't achieve what you're after.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the workaround I ended up with. But the more I think about it the more it makes sense why inheritance in EF shouldn't be modeled at the application level using BaseEntityTypeConfiguration classes because the way common base properties such as CanvasWidgetId are configured is based on the inheritance strategy (TPT, TPC, or TPH) and not the order of constructor calls of the configuration classes

Comment: Interesting point, this has encouraged me to go read a lot more about EF inheritance strategies, as I've only had to use EF inheritance in fairly simple cases. =D